# Is there a free tool available to build a strongly typed dataset schema from a Crystal Report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, dataset, datasource

I'm importing pre-created Crystal Reports into a report project, and I want to populate the data from a database call, so I can change data sources programatically.

There's a lot of fields here, though, in a lot of tables.  I don't want to build these datasets manually if I don't have to.  Is there a tool that will examine the Crystal Reports' metadata and generate a strongly-typed ADO.NET dataset from it?  It would save me a lot of time.

Comment: You say you want to populate the report from a database call. Is it necessary to load the data into an intermediate dataset? Or could you populate the report directly from the database?

Comment: I want to decouple it from the database, so we can easily control the data source from a connection string in the config file.

Comment: I've posted a solution which will allow you to control the data source from a connection string. Let me know if that doesn't suffice.

Comment: This really doesn't give me the level of decoupling I want.  I really would prefer to have my reports persistence ignorant, as this gives me more control over how they get their data, and allows me to create a common infrastructure for all of these reports.  Your answer would get me through the first door, but it's still manual code I have to write for every report.  +1 for a workable solution though.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Specifically what do you mean by `I really would prefer to have my reports persistence ignorant` and `it's still manual code I have to write for every report`

Comment: Persistence ignorant = the engine does not know or care where the data comes from.  A database, a text file, an in-memory data set, it does not care.  I don't want it to connect to a database.  This gives options in platform independence and testability.  The manual code means every report I have to import, I have to write into the class some scaffolding to make the report connection agnostic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like there is a mechanism like I want.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the datasource the report points to programmatically- you don't need to use an intermediate dataset. You simply look through each table in the report and update the datasource.

See below code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
            TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
            TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
            ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
            Tables CrTables ;

            cryRpt.Load("PUT CRYSTAL REPORT PATH HERE\CrystalReport1.rpt");

            crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "YOUR SERVER NAME";
            crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "YOUR DATABASE NAME";
            crConnectionInfo.UserID = "YOUR DATABASE USERNAME";
            crConnectionInfo.Password = "YOUR DATABASE PASSWORD";

            CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables ;
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
            {
                crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
                crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
            }

            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Taken from: http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-dynamic-login.htm